# Fetching Facebook data of the past year?

Tags: c#, c++, facebook, facebook-like, sharedpreferences

I would like to know if any preference status updates of Facebook users of a particular region can be fetched?

I am trying to study location based preferences on brand or likings of people of a particular geographical region. It can be either likes or status updates by searching key words. Is there any way to accomplish this other than hadoop?

I do not know where to start, so any answers, pointers or guidance will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at the Graph API?  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/graphapi/